# Error in node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/util.d.ts:1485:42 - error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: node.js, angular-material, node-modules

i have this problem any idea please !

[image]

**package.json** :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Same issue since 4 days , no workaround for now :(

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue too.

For me , The temporary fix was to do:

`npm i -D @types/node@17.0.41`

This installs a ***non-breaking*** version of the `@types/node` package as a dev Dependency to your project.

The reason we have to do this is that there appears to be a breaking changes with the `@types/node` package -  you can [Read more about the issue here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/64262)

A ***better*** way to fix is as follows:

If you wont want to add another dev dependency to your project, you can use `npm override` like this inside your `package.json` file to install the non-breaking version. This is the preferred method to fix errors like this:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.41"
  }
}
```

Read more about **npm override** [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides)